# Read xlsx with formating to a dataframe in python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I'm struggling with reading excel.xlxs file.
I have multi-level worksheet with color formatting and indents. So, there is a lot of patterns that could help me to separate data.

I want to separate data based on formatting, how can i do this?

Input:

[image: Input]

Expected output:

[image: Expected output in dataframe]

Excel as example:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BxYnTPl30-8C9tlFL8dgs8bRXfZ10DfQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please share the file as well?

Comment: @RupeshGoud its weight is above 10MB, i'll share an example

Comment: if you want to work on the data with regards to formatting, i would suggest having a look at [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html). i would love to work on something like this, as i am currently working on a project that showcases different ways of extracting data from Excel sheets using python